# Logstash Kafka output

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to send some "messages" to kafka using Logstash.

My problem is that the message is sent as a string "%{message}" and not the message

here is my config:

```
input {
    jdbc {
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxx"
      jdbc_user => "xxx"
      jdbc_password => "xxx"
      jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar"
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      schedule => "* * * * *"
      statement => "SELECT * from a WHERE updated_at > :sql_last_value    order by updated_at"
      use_column_value => true
      tracking_column => updated_at        
 }
 output {
      kafka {
            codec => plain {
                format => "%{message}"
            }
            topic_id => "mytopic"
    }
    file {
            codec => json_lines
            path => "/tmp/output_a.log"
    }
 }
```

As I mention above, when I dig into kafka messages I see "%{message}" and not the result from the select ... If I open /tmp/output_a.log the result it is there.

Any suggest ?

```
$bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopic --from-beginning
%{message}
2017-06-21T15:14:00.336Z %{host} %{message} (<- I tried here to remove the codec)
%{message}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved with

```
kafka {
            codec => json_lines
            topic_id => "mytopic"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid json overhead, try using just `lines`